# In Peter Corke‘s Robot Book, the same Function `rpy2r()` yields different results?

Tags: matlab, robotics

[image]

but matlab result:

```
>> R2=rpy2r(0.1,0.2,0.3)

R2 =

    0.9363   -0.2751    0.2184
    0.2896    0.9564   -0.0370
   -0.1987    0.0978    0.9752

>> [theta,v]=tr2angvec(R)

theta =

    0.3655


v =

    0.1886    0.5834    0.7900

>> [v,lambda]=eig(R)

v =

   0.6944 + 0.0000i   0.6944 + 0.0000i   0.1886 + 0.0000i
  -0.0792 - 0.5688i  -0.0792 + 0.5688i   0.5834 + 0.0000i
  -0.1073 + 0.4200i  -0.1073 - 0.4200i   0.7900 + 0.0000i


lambda =

   0.9339 + 0.3574i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.9339 - 0.3574i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i
```

As the pic shows, the same function gives different outputs, has any one else found the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can't read Chinese, but apparently the function `tr2angvec`only returns one rotation angle and its corresponding vector. Matlab's `eig` returns the full matrix of eigenvectors and a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues.

Because of this, the last column given by `eig` is the vector provided by `tr2angvec`.  Note that `theta=0.3655` while the real eigenvalue is one (because rotations do not change length). Then notice that the real part of the imaginary eigenvalues is `0.9339`, and that `acos(0.9339)=0.365626358 rad`.

Then recall that the imaginary eigenvalues of a rotation matrix are `cos(theta) + i sin(theta)` and `cos(theta) - i sin(theta)`.

Comment: Thx.I got you.and I find my answer now.In old book,rpy2r: roll-pitch-yaw angles are defined as a rotation sequence about the Z- then y- then x-axes.But in toolbox 10.3,rotation sequence about theX- then y- then Z-axes.So we need use rpy2r(roll,pitch,yaw,'zyx'),can get same ans.